# Average Formula in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I need some help with eliminating a #DIV/0! error message. I am trying to consolidate and calculate an average from multiple spreadsheets within the same workbook using the following formula: =IF('Cass County'!G23=0,"",AVERAGE('Cass County:Marion County'!G23)). G23 is just making reference to one of the many cells I am calculating. I have approximately 12 spreadsheets (tabs). It calculates correctly if I have a value in the cell; however, if I have a 0 or blank it gives me the #DIV/0! error.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tried to replicate in Excel 2013, but I don't have the same problem - when I have blanks, or even text, the `AVERAGE()` ignores those values. When I have zeroes, it treats them as numbers and includes them in the calculation. What happens if you try to do the same thing in a basic form in a new workbook? ie `=AVERAGE('Sheet1:Sheet3'!A1)`. Same problem?

Comment: I'm also not able to replicate in Excel 2010. What happens if you just have the `AVERAGE` function without the `IF`?

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if the cell format is 'General' and not 'Text'? I suspect that the contents of the cell is the text '0' instead of numeric 0, which causes the IF statement to calculate AVERAGE instead of just displaying "" (empty cell).

[image]